# Pandas: Select all rows between two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get all the rows in a dataset that are between two rows where a certain value is met. Is it possible to do that? I cannot sort the dataset because then all the crucial information will be lost.

Edit:
The dataset contains data as such:

```
Index| game_clock| quarter | event_type
0    | 711       | 1       | 1
1    | 710       | 1       | 3
2    | 709       | 2       | 4
3    | 708       | 3       | 2
4    | 707       | 4       | 4
5    | 706       | 4       | 1
```

I want to slice the dataset so that I get subsets of all the rows that are between event_type (1 or 2) and (1 or 2).

Edit 2:
Suppose the dataset is as follows:

```
    A         B
0   1  0.278179
1   2  0.069914
2   2  0.633110
3   4  0.584766
4   3  0.581232
5   3  0.677205
6   3  0.687155
7   1  0.438927
8   4  0.320927
9   3  0.570552
10  3  0.479849
11  1  0.861074
12  3  0.834805
13  4  0.105766
14  1  0.060408
15  4  0.596882
16  1  0.792395
17  3  0.226356
18  4  0.535201
19  1  0.136066
20  1  0.372244
21  1  0.151977
22  4  0.429822
23  1  0.792706
24  2  0.406957
25  1  0.177850
26  1  0.909252
27  1  0.545331
28  4  0.100497
29  2  0.718721
```

The subsets I would like to get are indexed as:

```
[0], [1], [2], [3:8], [8:12],
 [12:15], [15:20], [20], [21], [22:24], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28: ]
```

Comment: Can you add data sample? Are data duplicated?

Comment: @jezrael Yeah bad practice on my part. I edited the question.

Comment: Thank you, `event_type (1 or 2) and (1 or 2).` is correct? Not typo?

Comment: I'm curious as to how you'd do it without looping. Because if looping is allowed, it seems that you'd only need a loop that goes through the data, finds first occurrence (as begin index), then the next occurrence would be the end index, and so on...

Comment: @jezrael I want the subset's first row event_id to be 1 or 2 and the subset's last row event_id to be 1 or 2. I know it's not the correct code but I used pseudo-code to make it more clear.

Comment: @IMCoins I am trying to find a more elegant way in order to save time and complexity because the dataset is too large.

Comment: @ThP So you want to remove the start and end of the dataset if not 1 or 2?

Comment: @AntonvBR I want to get everything that is between 1 and 2.

Comment: `Between 1 and 2` or `Between (1 or 2) and (1 or 2)` ? And is looping allowed ?

Comment: OK, what about more general sample e.g. `np.random.seed(314) df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4], 30), 'B':np.random.rand(30)})` ? Can you add desired output with this?

Comment: @jezrael I think I understood. He wants to split the dataframe in n dataframes between (1 or 2) and (1 or 2). So he gets index 1,2 in 1 (this is between 1 and 2) and index 4 in another (this is between 2 and 1)

Comment: @AntonvBR - yes, I understand. I add data only if OP need remove starts and end data to first `1,2` and remove rows from last `1,2` or somsthing else.

Comment: @jezrael I edited the answer once more. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I think that sample data and expected result confused me a bit. Did you try something like `df[-df['event_type'].isin(1,2)]`. Notice the `-`, it  negates the `isin(1,2)` expression, giving you the rows whose event_type is not 1 or 2. The result maintains the original indexing, so you can assume that rows with contiguous index are a block that was placed between rows whose event_type was 1 or 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
a = pd.factorize(df['A'].isin([1,2]).iloc[::-1].cumsum().sort_index())[0]
print (a)
[ 0  1  2  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  6  6  7  7  7  8  9 10 10 11
 12 13 14 15 15]
```

---

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(a)))
print (dfs[0])
   A         B
0  1  0.278179

print (dfs[1])
   A         B
1  2  0.069914

print (dfs[2])
   A        B
2  2  0.63311

print (dfs[3])
   A         B
3  4  0.584766
4  3  0.581232
5  3  0.677205
6  3  0.687155
7  1  0.438927

print (dfs[4])
    A         B
8   4  0.320927
9   3  0.570552
10  3  0.479849
11  1  0.861074
```

Explanation:

```
#check values to boolean mask
a = df['A'].isin([1,2])
#reverse Series
b = df['A'].isin([1,2]).iloc[::-1]
#cumulative sum
c = df['A'].isin([1,2]).iloc[::-1].cumsum()
#get original order
d = df['A'].isin([1,2]).iloc[::-1].cumsum().sort_index()
#factorize for keys in dictionary of DataFrames
e = pd.factorize(df['A'].isin([1,2]).iloc[::-1].cumsum().sort_index())[0]
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([a,pd.Series(b.values),pd.Series(c.values),d,pd.Series(e)], 
               axis=1, keys=list('abcde'))
print (df)
        a      b   c   d   e
0    True   True   1  16   0
1    True  False   1  15   1
2    True   True   2  14   2
3   False   True   3  13   3
4   False   True   4  13   3
5   False   True   5  13   3
6   False   True   6  13   3
7    True  False   6  13   3
8   False   True   7  12   4
9   False   True   8  12   4
10  False   True   9  12   4
11   True  False   9  12   4
12  False  False   9  11   5
13  False   True  10  11   5
14   True  False  10  11   5
15  False   True  11  10   6
16   True  False  11  10   6
17  False  False  11   9   7
18  False   True  12   9   7
19   True  False  12   9   7
20   True  False  12   8   8
21   True  False  12   7   9
22  False   True  13   6  10
23   True  False  13   6  10
24   True  False  13   5  11
25   True  False  13   4  12
26   True  False  13   3  13
27   True   True  14   2  14
28  False   True  15   1  15
29   True   True  16   1  15
```

Comment: Yep.. this looks like it does it. I was having a hard time zipping the things together.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer answers my question perfectly!

Comment: Super, give me some time for explatanion.

Comment: I learned here how to approach the problem - Using pd.factorize and group them by new index. Also, you can always pick the repeating index if you need only that.

Answer (score 1):

That list still doesn't make sense. Sometimes you include first occurence, sometimes not. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(314) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4], 30), 'B':np.random.rand(30)})

ar = np.where(df.A.isin((1,2)))[0]
ids = list(zip(ar,ar[1:]))

for item in ids:
    print(df.iloc[item[0]:item[1],:])
```

ids are now:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 7), (7, 11), (11, 14), (14, 16), (16, 19), (19, 20),
(20, 21), (21, 23), (23, 24), (24, 25), (25, 26), (26, 27), (27, 29)]
```

This will include 1 or 2 in the start and stop at 1,2 in the end.

Comment: there is `np.random.seed(314)`, so same output always ;)

Comment: @jezrael yep I noted.!

Comment: @jezrael Can we pass a tuple instead of item[0]:item[1] to iloc?

Comment: The logic behind it is as such: I only want to keep everything in between and the last value which is 1 or 2. If the dataset starts with 1 or 2 then that is valid subset because it's last element is 1 or 2 and there is no other occurrence before that.

Comment: @ThP ok so the 1 or 2 should stop the subset not start it? Let me think.

Comment: @AntonvBR Yeah but it must also be included in it.